# How to use values from spring tags in web-controller?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am writing web-app using Spring MVC. As a view I use JSP. I want to bind data from spring tags and params in controller method. F.e. I have a add user form:

```
<form:form action="/add_user" commandName="user">
    <div>
        First name:<form:input path="firstName"/><br>
        Last name:<form:textarea path="lastName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add user">
    </div>
</form:form>
```

and a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(??? User newUser ????) {
      userService.add(newUser);
      return "redirect:/users";
    }
    ...
}
```

What should I put instead of ??????? between the brackets?
I would be overjoy if you give me detaile tutorial or plain documentation (not "http://docs.spring.io/")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow **micha**'s answer to make your code working. For more details and basic concepts about the form submission and displaying the value from `Controller` to jsp page you can look at the tutorials http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-handling-tutorial-and-example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@ModelAttribute` to your `newUser` parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User newUser) {
  ..
}
```

Have a look at the [form submission](http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) guide. This guide uses Thymeleaf instead of JSP but the form handling inside the controller is the same.

Comment: I've got:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute`